# Почему происходит exited, segmentation fault

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  char **words=NULL; // указатель на слова
  int num_words=0; // кол во слов
  char *delim=" \t\n,.!?:";
  int size_file=0; //размер файла
  FILE *fp=fopen("test.txt", "r");
  fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
  size_file=ftell(fp); //находим размер файла
  printf("%d\n", size_file);
  char *buffer=calloc(size_file+1, sizeof(char*)); //буфер 

  if(buffer==NULL) {
    printf("Ошибка выделения памяти\n");
    exit(-1);
  }

  fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
  fread(buffer, 1, size_file, fp);
  printf("\nТекст файла\n\n");

  printf("%s\n", buffer);
  char *istr=strtok(buffer, delim);
  while(istr) {
    words=realloc(words, (num_words+1)*sizeof(char*));
    words[num_words++]=istr;
    istr=strtok(NULL, delim);
    //printf("%s\n", istr);
  }

  /*for (int i=0; i<num_words;i++) {
  printf("%p\n", words[i]);
  }*/
  printf("Количество символов в файле :%d\n", size_file);
  printf("Количество слов в файле :%d\n\n", num_words);
  for (int i=0; i<num_words; i++) {
    puts(words[i]);
  }

  printf("\nНахождение одинаковых слов\n");
  for (int i=0; i<num_words;i++) {
    for (int j=0; i<num_words;j++) {
      if (strcmp(words[i],words[j])==0) {
      //тут пытаюсь реализовать счетчик сколько раз повторялось слово, пока не выходит.
      }
    }
  }
  fclose(fp);

  return 0;
}
```

И как можно реализовать подсчет повторений каждого слова(например "the"=3, то есть встретилось в тексте 3 раза и т д)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> И как можно реализовать подсчет повторений каждого слова(например
>   "the"=3, то есть встретилось в тексте 3 раза и т д)

Например, (сильно не меняя идею, которую вы пыталиcь реализовать во вложенных циклах) так:

```
  int *wcnt = calloc(num_words, sizeof(int));
  char *is_first = calloc(num_words, sizeof(char));
  printf("\nНахождение одинаковых слов\n");
  for (int i=0; i<num_words;i++) {
    wcnt[i]++;
    for (int j=0; j<num_words;j++) {
      if (i != j && strcmp(words[i],words[j])==0) {
      //тут пытаюсь реализовать счетчик сколько раз повторялось слово, пока не выходит.
        if (wcnt[i]++ == 1 && i < j)
          is_first[i] = 1;
      }
    }
  }

  for (int i=0; i<num_words; i++) {
    if (wcnt[i] == 1 || is_first[i])
      printf("%s\t %d\n", words[i], wcnt[i]);
  }
```

Более эффективно можно решить ту же задачу, используя сортировку (одинаковые слова окажутся рядом) или map ([хэш-таблицу](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B5%D1%88-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0)), хранящую в качестве ключа слово, а в качестве данных счетчик.

Конечно,, более эффективно реализовать `is_first[]` как битовый вектор (займет в 8 раз меньше памяти), но не захотел загружать вас еще и операциями с битами.

Answer (score 1):

У вас в последнем цикле опечатка.

```
  printf("Количество символов в файле :%d\n", size_file);
  printf("Количество слов в файле :%d\n\n", num_words);
  for (int i=0; i<num_words; i++) {
    puts(words[i]);
  }
    int *cnt = (int*) malloc(num_words*sizeof(int));//массив повторений
  printf("\nНахождение одинаковых слов\n");
  for (int i=0; i<num_words;i++) {
      cnt[i] = 0;
      for(int j=0; /*ошибка в виде 'i'*/ j<num_words;j++)
      if (strcmp(words[i],words[j])==0) cnt[i]++;
  }
  fclose(fp);

  //вывод нужного кол-ва элементов одинаковых элементов (т.е. в данном случае первых cnt[0])
    printf("\n%d",cnt[0]);
  return 0;
}
```